# error in safely removing drive

Tags: disk

It used to work perfectly, when I connect my external hard drive, and try to *safely remove* it, it shows the following error:

> error opening /dev/sdc for fsync: Device or resource busy

I checked that no IO operations are being done currently. What is this error, and how can I *safely remove* my drive again? For now, I'm putting my computer to sleep before plugging out the device, is that workaround safe as well?

I am using ubuntu 20.04LTS.

Comment: Putting computer to sleep may not be safe because that may not close the disks properly. Shutting down may be the only safe alternative.

Comment: Here a similar error message which was due to bad blocks: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176955/external-drive-causes-all-processes-talking-to-it-to-freeze-has-the-drive-faile If that is the case, then indeed your drive may be failing.